# Preload scene in unity

Tags: unity, preload

I have a game with two scenes, menu and maingame. I have uploaded the game to googleplay. However when I open the game and click on the play button in the menu scene, the next scene (maingame) takes about 4-5 seconds to load. Is there any way to load the maingame along with the menu so that there is no delay in loading?

**EDIT**

I have added code to the MainMenu.cs file so that when the game starts the LoadSceneAsync function is called and allowSceneActivation is set to false. Once the "play" button is pressed, the activation is set to true. The first time the game loads, there is still a bit of delay however if the player dies and I go the main menu and press play again, there is no delay.

```
AsyncOperation async;

void Start()
{        
    async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);       
    async.allowSceneActivation = false;
}

public void PlayBtnPressed()
{
   async.allowSceneActivation = true;
   AudioManager.audiomanager.Play("PlayButton");       
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Level loading in Unity is usually achieved via `AsyncOperation` or other non-blocking operations. However, one can find several different solutions when using these.

Comment: @Vaillancourt , so far I haven't added any async ops as I'm not sure how to do so...Once the game loads, it directly goes to scene 1 and if the player hits on play (in scene 1), then scene 2 loads...

Comment: @liggiorgio , is there any example or sample code that you can share?

Answer (score 2):

## Scene Loading

#### Basic

Tested this in a new project. The idea is to start scene preloading when `Return` button is pressed and save `AsyncOperation` that is doing it, disallow scene activation for it and allow it when you need the scene to be loaded as soon as it's ready.

I would expect it to be loaded into memory, be careful if you are RAM-bounded because both scenes will take up memory space until one is unloaded.

Reproduce:

1. Create a new project.
2. Create 2 scenes:

   - "menu"
   - "maingame"
3. Add both scenes to `Build Settings`.
4. Open "menu" scene.
5. Create `GameObject` and add `PreloadSceneInUnity` component to it.
6. Enter playmode.
7. Press `Return` and see "maingame (is loading)" in Hierarchy window.
8. Press `Space` - "maingame" scene will open.

### Code

**Git:** [Preload scene in unity](https://github.com/PixelLifetime/unity-game-development-stack-exchange/tree/master/Assets/%7B%40%23%7D%20Answers/Preload%20scene%20in%20unity)

```cs
using System.Collections;

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PreloadSceneInUnity : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string _sceneName = "maingame";
    public string _SceneName => this._sceneName;

    private AsyncOperation _asyncOperation;

    private IEnumerator LoadSceneAsyncProcess(string sceneName)
    {
        // Begin to load the Scene you have specified.
        this._asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);

        // Don't let the Scene activate until you allow it to.
        this._asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = false;

        while (!this._asyncOperation.isDone)
        {
            Debug.Log($"[scene]:{sceneName} [load progress]: {this._asyncOperation.progress}");

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) && this._asyncOperation == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Started Scene Preloading");

            // Start scene preloading.
            this.StartCoroutine(this.LoadSceneAsyncProcess(sceneName: this._sceneName));
        }

        // Press the space key to activate the Scene.
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && this._asyncOperation != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Allowed Scene Activation");

            this._asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Advanced

If you are not satisfied with how scene loading works in `UnityEngine.SceneManagement` - I suggest you take a look at `Addressables` package that Unity provides, it has support for scene loading as well, but be aware that it's a lot more complicated to get into and there is a learning curve that requires to learn quite a few more things before scene loading.

Comment: Just curious: What's the purpose of the first `yield return null;`  in `LoadSceneAsyncProcess`?

Comment: @Philipp I have tested without it and it doesn't make a difference, I guess it's redundant unless you need to wait a frame before loading scene async, but it's from the official documentation about `AsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation`. I guess it's from some old times when it mattered, I remember having this issue in one of my projects, but my memory of it now is very vague and something tells me it's related to Editor scripting. I am going to remove it since it doesn't seem relevant anymore, good catch, thanks.

Comment: @Philipp It might be related to this - https://answers.unity.com/questions/755196/yield-return-null-vs-yield-return-waitforendoffram.html - `yield return null;` will execute this before `LateUpdate`, maybe it matters for some projects, or some logic should be finished in `Update` before user could possibly jump to another scene. I cannot come up with a situation like that, so it's based on my hunch.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ , thanks a lot for the code...just one question. Is there any way to do these once the splash screen is being shown?

Comment: @singlearrowgames yes, just start scene loading whenever you need. If you want to load 2 scenes at the same time you will need to be in some other scene. So I would have (1) scene with splash-screen and preloading of scenes (2) and (3). But because if you change a scene - data (about operation) of unloaded scene is lost, so you will need to save it in some other scene. By default there is `DontDestroyOnLoad` scene which you can utilise. Or you could have scene (1) being loaded additively, or other scenes being loaded additively [I am not sure, I will need to experiment with it sometime].

Comment: @singlearrowgames what I would do is [first] try - make some manager that contains `AsyncOperation` data of each scene currently being loaded in the background. Use `DontDestroyOnLoad` on it in the (1) scene where it lives. (1) scene - should be very lightweight, used just for preloading if you want preloading to start asap. Then I would use this manager to request preloading and loading of a scene. If scene is ready `isDone` it will load it without waiting.

Comment: @singlearrowgames [second] try if `DontDestroyOnLoad` wouldn't work for some reason, I would have (1) scene as a `main` scene and all of the other scenes would be loaded and unloaded `Additively`, so any state saved in scene (1) will always be there and it will always be loaded. This will complicate scene management, so for simple apps where you don't need to do this functionality to support other features I would go with the [first] solution.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ , thanks for all the help.....

Comment: @Philipp https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/loadsceneasync-allowsceneactivation-flag-is-ignored-in-awake > "In 2018, you could get around this by starting a coroutine and waiting one tick. This workaround no longer works for 2019." This is probably it. Waiting `yield return null` so scene loading would work in Awake.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_, I have edited the original post and added some code....There is still an issue the first time the game loads....the splash screen I was talking about was the one in player settings....

Comment: @singlearrowgames could you make a gif or youtube video that shows the delay you are talking about? It's hard to tell because it could be anything, if the scene is complex and has lots of textures/meshes etc. it could take some time to load even after it was preloaded, or it could be that it's not yet at `> 0.9f` when you press `PlayButton` and it's still in process of loading.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_, I will try to make a gif....thanks...is there any way to call this in the awake function...I tried calling in awake, but it always loads the next scene automatically....

Comment: @singlearrowgames not sure, probably adding `yield return null` but is there any reason to call it on `Awake`? I believe `Awake` and `Start` are called on the same frame, just in a different order.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_, oh...I was under the impression that awake gets called first.....

Comment: @singlearrowgames it does, first all `Awake`s then all `Start`s on the same frame. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html `Awake` will be called if the script is `enabled = false` (GameObject has to be active) but `Start` won't.If everything is enabled and active `Awake` and `Start` are called on the same frame. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34652545/6603717

Comment: @singlearrowgames this actually interested me to write multi scene loading and test my theory. Since the title here is a little bit different from what I would expect to answer - I have created a question which describes the situation from my perspective from what I understood and answered it. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/185627/preload-multiple-scenes-at-the-same-time-and-activate-them-on-demand-in-unity/185628#185628

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_, thanks for this......

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can load the next scene asynchronously using SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync() using coroutines. You can use this strategy on a splash / loading screen if you're wanting to see it load before showing the menu.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        // Press the space key to start coroutine
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            // Use a coroutine to load the Scene in the background
            StartCoroutine(LoadYourAsyncScene());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadYourAsyncScene()
    {

        AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Scene2");

        // yield to other processes until the scene is loaded
        while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        // Do something here like enabling the play button or closing the splash/loading screen
    }
}
```

Code example from: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html

EDIT: As has been indicated in the comments, if you want to control when the scene loads, you can use the allowSceneActivation flag on the above AsyncOperation object.
asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = false;
When you want it to load the next scene:
asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = true;

Comment: One problem with this is that the scene will immediately appear and execute as soon as the async loading is finished. Would you know some convenient way to load it but not start rendering and updating it yet?

Comment: @Philipp https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-allowSceneActivation.html

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ Maybe you would like to write an own answer which explains and demonstrates how to use this property to load a scene in the background without switching to it immediately?

Comment: @Philipp I will write it up, thanks.