# Preload multiple scenes at the same time and activate them on demand in Unity. [Unity, async, simultaneous]

Tags: unity, scene, preload, async

[Preload scene in unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/185528/preload-scene-in-unity/185548?noredirect=1#comment334331_185548) - this question tells us about how we can pre-load a scene in Unity and load it on demand. What it doesn't tell us - how do we pre-load multiple scenes at the same time and also keep the other scenes in memory waiting to be activated when we load another scene?

Use case: pre-loading multiple scenes at the start of the application, so they are ready when required. Example:

1. You have a `[Scene] Intro` which takes `20s` to complete where you start pre-reloading `[Scene] Main Menu` that takes `10s` to load. When `[Scene] Main Menu` has finished pre-loading, you still have `10s` to spare, those could be used to pre-load `[Scene] Main Game`.
2. You have a `[Scene] Main Menu`. Depending on user choice you load `[Scene] Main Game` or `[Scene] Sandbox`. You pre-load both scenes while user is still in `[Scene] Main Menu`. When user makes their choice, chosen pre-loaded scene is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

Currently we can't do that in certain cases.

### Long asnwer

[AsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-allowSceneActivation.html) tells us:

> When `allowSceneActivation` is set to false then progress is stopped at `0.9`. The `isDone` is then maintained at `false`. When `allowSceneActivation` is set to true `isDone` can complete. While `isDone` is false, the `AsyncOperation` queue is stalled. For example, if a `LoadSceneAsync.allowSceneActivation` is set to `false`, and another `AsyncOperation` (e.g. `SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync` ) is initialized, the last operation will not be called before the first `allowSceneActivation` is set to `true`.

Which means that there is an order to load pre-loaded scenes. If we pre-load scenes `[Scene] Main Game` and `[Scene] Sandbox` in this order, we can't activate `[Scene] Sandbox` until we activate `[Scene] Main Game`. If we first activate `[Scene] Main Game` it will activate without a problem if it was pre-loaded first, and following we can activate `[Scene] Sandbox` because the queue is empty.

In conclusion, right now we can only load scenes in specific order.

***More:*** [[ISSUE] Activating multiple scene at the same time via AsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation](https://forum.unity.com/threads/issue-activating-multiple-scene-at-the-same-time-via-asyncoperation-allowsceneactivation.624604/) .

### Solutions

1. Use Addressables and make scenes as prefabs. Load/Unload instances of this prefab in a manner like you would load/unload scenes.

### Code

**Git:** [Preload multiple scenes at the same time and activate them on demand in Unity. [Unity, async, simultaneous]](https://github.com/PixelLifetime/unity-game-development-stack-exchange/tree/master/Assets/%7B%40%23%7D%20Answers/Preload%20multiple%20scenes%20at%20the%20same%20time%20and%20activate%20them%20on%20demand%20in%20Unity.%20%5BUnity%2C%20async%2C%20simultaneous%5D)

I have tested this with both `SceneManager` and `Addressables`.

`PreloadSceneManager.cs`

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AddressableAssets;
using UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations;
using UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.ResourceProviders;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PreloadSceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Dictionary<string, AsyncOperation> _sceneName_sceneLoadAsyncOperation = new Dictionary<string, AsyncOperation>();

    public AsyncOperation PreloadSceneAsync(string sceneName, LoadSceneMode loadSceneMode)
    {
        if (this._sceneName_sceneLoadAsyncOperation.TryGetValue(key: sceneName, value: out AsyncOperation loadSceneAsyncOperation))
            return loadSceneAsyncOperation;

        loadSceneAsyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(
            sceneName: sceneName,
            mode: loadSceneMode
        );

        loadSceneAsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = false;

        this._sceneName_sceneLoadAsyncOperation.Add(
            key: sceneName,
            value: loadSceneAsyncOperation
        );
        
        return loadSceneAsyncOperation;
    }

    public AsyncOperation LoadSceneAsync(string sceneName, LoadSceneMode loadSceneMode)
    {
        if (this._sceneName_sceneLoadAsyncOperation.TryGetValue(key: sceneName, value: out AsyncOperation loadSceneAsyncOperation))
        {
            loadSceneAsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = true;

            return loadSceneAsyncOperation;
        }
        
        loadSceneAsyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(
            sceneName: sceneName,
            mode: loadSceneMode
        );
        
        return loadSceneAsyncOperation;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, AsyncOperationHandle<SceneInstance>> _sceneName_sceneLoadAsyncOperationHandle = new Dictionary<string, AsyncOperationHandle<SceneInstance>>();

    public AsyncOperationHandle<SceneInstance> AddressablesPreloadSceneAsync(string key, LoadSceneMode loadSceneMode)
    {
        if (this._sceneName_sceneLoadAsyncOperationHandle.TryGetValue(key: key, value: out AsyncOperationHandle<SceneInstance> loadSceneAsyncOperationHandle))
            return loadSceneAsyncOperationHandle;

        loadSceneAsyncOperationHandle = Addressables.LoadSceneAsync(
            key: key,
            loadMode: loadSceneMode,
            activateOnLoad: false
        );
        
        this._sceneName_sceneLoadAsyncOperationHandle.Add(
            key: key,
            value: loadSceneAsyncOperationHandle
        );

        return loadSceneAsyncOperationHandle;
    }

    public AsyncOperationHandle<SceneInstance> AddressablesLoadSceneAsync(string key, LoadSceneMode loadSceneMode)
    {
        if (this._sceneName_sceneLoadAsyncOperationHandle.TryGetValue(key: key, value: out AsyncOperationHandle<SceneInstance> loadSceneAsyncOperationHandle))
        {
            loadSceneAsyncOperationHandle.Result.ActivateAsync();

            return loadSceneAsyncOperationHandle;
        }

        loadSceneAsyncOperationHandle = Addressables.LoadSceneAsync(
            key: key,
            loadMode: loadSceneMode,
            activateOnLoad: true
        );

        return loadSceneAsyncOperationHandle;
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(target: this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

`SceneLoader.cs`

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations;
using UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.ResourceProviders;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IEnumerator LoadSceneAsyncProcess(string sceneName, AsyncOperation asyncOperation)
    {
        while (!asyncOperation.isDone)
        {
            Debug.Log($"[scene]:{sceneName} [percent complete]: {asyncOperation.progress}");

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadSceneAsyncProcess(string sceneName, AsyncOperationHandle<SceneInstance> asyncOperationHandle)
    {
        while (!asyncOperationHandle.IsDone)
        {
            Debug.Log($"[scene]:{sceneName} [percent complete]: {asyncOperationHandle.PercentComplete}");

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    [SerializeField] private PreloadSceneManager _preloadSceneManager;
    public PreloadSceneManager _PreloadSceneManager => this._preloadSceneManager;

    [SerializeField] private string _sceneNameOrKey = "[Scene] Preload Scene 1";
    public string _SceneNameOrKey => this._sceneNameOrKey;

    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _loadSceneKeyCode = KeyCode.Alpha1;
    public KeyCode _LoadSceneKeyCode => this._loadSceneKeyCode;

    [SerializeField] private LoadSceneMode _loadSceneMode = LoadSceneMode.Additive;
    public LoadSceneMode _LoadSceneMode => this._loadSceneMode;

    private void Update()
    {
        //if (Input.GetKeyDown(key: KeyCode.Return))
        //{
        //  // Start scene preloading.

        //  Debug.Log($"Preload [scene]: {this._sceneName}");

        //  AsyncOperation asyncOperation = this._preloadSceneManager.PreloadSceneAsync(
        //      sceneName: this._sceneName,
        //      loadSceneMode: LoadSceneMode.Additive
        //  );

        //  this.StartCoroutine(
        //      routine: this.LoadSceneAsyncProcess(
        //          sceneName: this._sceneName,
        //          asyncOperation: asyncOperation
        //      )
        //  );
        //}
        
        //if (Input.GetKeyDown(key: this._loadSceneKeyCode))
        //{
        //  Debug.Log($"Load [scene]: {this._sceneName}");

        //  AsyncOperation asyncOperation = this._preloadSceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(
        //      sceneName: this._sceneName,
        //      loadSceneMode: LoadSceneMode.Additive
        //  );
        //}

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(key: KeyCode.Return))
        {
            // Start scene preloading.

            Debug.Log($"Preload [scene]: {this._sceneNameOrKey}");

            AsyncOperationHandle<SceneInstance> asyncOperationHandle = this._preloadSceneManager.AddressablesPreloadSceneAsync(
                key: this._sceneNameOrKey,
                loadSceneMode: this._loadSceneMode
            );

            this.StartCoroutine(
                routine: this.LoadSceneAsyncProcess(
                    sceneName: this._sceneNameOrKey,
                    asyncOperationHandle: asyncOperationHandle
                )
            );
        }
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(key: this._loadSceneKeyCode))
        {
            Debug.Log($"Load [scene]: {this._sceneNameOrKey}");

            this._preloadSceneManager.AddressablesLoadSceneAsync(
                key: this._sceneNameOrKey,
                loadSceneMode: this._loadSceneMode
            );
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(target: this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you can preload multiple scenes if they all use `LoadSceneMode.Additive`. If any one of them uses `LoadSceneMode.Single` then it will block the Async queue.